# Remain data that input in text field

Tags: titanium

My case is that I want to remain/save entered data on text field and will make a drop down list of my previous entered data when I click on the text field and also if i close and open back the application, the entered data will still be in the drop down list. Example, i entered "abc123" in the text field and i press enter on a button, it will save "abc123" in the drop down list of the text field and if i quit the application and enter again, "abc123" will still be in the drop down list.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
backgroundColor: 'white',
});

var txtfield = Ti.UI.createTextField({
});

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
title: 'go'
});

win.add(btn);
win.add(txtfield);
win.open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to save the values to SQLite or Ti.App.Properties.

Here is a working example :

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white',
    layout : 'vertical'
});

var txtfield = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    hintText : 'Enter new values...',
    top : 0
});

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    top : 10
});

var data = (Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('itemList')) ? Ti.App.Properties.getList('itemList') : [];
Ti.API.info('data is ' + data);
var m = [];
if (data)
data.forEach(function(item) {

    m.push(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:item}));

});
Ti.API.info('M is ' + m);
if (m.length > 0)
picker.add(m);

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
top : 10,
width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
title : 'go'
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var s = [];
if (Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('itemList')) {
    Ti.API.info('Property found');
    s = Ti.App.Properties.getList('itemList');
}
Ti.API.info('S is ' + s);
s.push(txtfield.value);
Ti.App.Properties.setList('itemList', s);
picker.add(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:txtfield.value}));
txtfield.value = '';
});

win.add(btn);
win.add(txtfield);
win.add(picker);
win.open();
```

Comment: thanks, hini! that's working well but if i want to replace picker to a drop down list only, like this image http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC14929.png

Comment: Mobile controls differ from desktop ones, there is no out of the box drop down list for Titanium, if you wanted one you'll need to create it from scratch

Comment: meaning i'll have to one by one using view, scrollbar, etc. ?

Comment: @Emmanuel: You can create your own dropdown list. Since mobile devices does not have such a control. You may do it using a textField and a tableView

Answer (score 0):

Definitely recommend to use sessionStorage or localStorage